# Which particular data structure should I use if I want a persistent balanced search tree?

Tags: data-structures, balanced-search-trees, binary-search-trees, persistent-data-structure

As title, I'm trying to implement a text editor with the rope data structure, which is backed by binary search tree.

Since I want it to have persistent undos, the underlaying data structure should also be persistent.

I know that there is an candidate like randomized immutable treap, I'd like to know if there are other candidates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many data structures for [balanced search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree); pick any one.  Then, you can make it persistent using [path copying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Path_copying), or Driscoll, Sarnak, Sleator, and Tarjan's technique -- these techniques are generic and can be applied to any tree data structure.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks a lot!